# Using multiple GET parameters using history.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I am using [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) to dynamically update the query parameters. But there is one problem is i use  History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"); it removes all other existing parameters of the URL. Is is possible to not overwrite the existing parameters and add the new state to the existing one? Thanks in advance

Comment: History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1&state2=2&state3=3");

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a better solution also, but I used this library called jquery BBQ, see:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html

and did it like this:

```
function updateURLParam(key, value) {
    var qs = $.param.querystring(window.location.href, key+"=" + value);
    History.replaceState(null, null, qs);
};
```

This will update just the parameter you want and leave the others alone.